# data.buffer.length returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have input Readable stream coming in via an external node library. I am trying to read and get the ArrayBuffer and convert it to something else for my program.

```
input.on(‘data’, function(data){
console.log(data); //returns <Buffer 73 fe 74 fe 95 fe 95 fe b6 fe b6 fe 00 ff 01 ff 37 ff 36 ff 8f ff 8f ff 10 00 10 00 65 00 66 00 95 00 95 00 79 00 7a 00 1b 00 1a 00 be ff be ff 56 ff ... >

console.log(data.buffer); // returns — ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 300 }

console.log(data.buffer.length); //returns undefined
console.log(data.buffer[0]); //returns undefined
});
```

If the data.buffer is an `ArrayBuffer`, why am I not able to access it at all?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data variable is a `Buffer` itself and by getting `data.buffer` you are getting the underlying `ArrayBuffer`.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_buffer

So you should either do something like:

```
console.log(data.length);
console.log(data[0]);
```

Or get the data.buffer but be aware that ArrayBuffers don't have much in common with "normal" JS arrays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

http://www.javascripture.com/ArrayBuffer

Comment: This seems to make sense but I am trying to access the value of the underlying Array Buffer to convert it an Audio Buffer. 
How can I access those ArrayBuffer values if I can't access `data.buffer[0]` etc.?

Comment: That can be tricky and really depends on what you are going to do with the data. In general case - you want to use DataView object which provides interfaces for the ArrayBuffer interactions. Check out this page https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView and the second URL from my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: btw you can check that AB's size by printing data.buffer.byteLength

Comment: I might be so confused between Buffer, ArrayBuffer and TypedArrays and now DataView. Still not sure why data.buffer[0] would return undefined if it's there. What is point of having `.buffer` accessor then?

Comment: Let's forget about the ArrayBuffer for now. So you want to grab that data and convert it to the AudioBuffer, right?

Comment: Check out this npm package - I think you could just grab your data var and convert it to AB with their lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-buffer-from Something like var myAudio = createBuffer(data)

Comment: Yeah, but I need to deinterleave the array buffer stuff myself as per my `audio interface` and `interleave` it in a different format. That's why I've been trying to access the lower level `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: ok, but you don't really need to mess with the AB for that. NodeJS Buffer is a wrapper for the AB. You could use entries() to iterate and write() to modify bytes. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_entries

Comment: Ah, so `Node` restricts the use of `ArrayBuffer` by doing data.buffer[0] etc.? And the only way to do is to use Views or entries?

Comment: Well, I'd say that AB is restricted that way by design, but Node gives us Buffer which adds those useful iteration / writing / reading stuff on a top